# Reducing number of conditional statements in R?

Tags: r, statistics, modeling

I have this massive block of code that has different if statements and different for statement for these if statements. Is there a way that I will be able to reduce the number of if and for loops in this code to make it more condensed and efficient?

```
library(tidyverse)

occ_simulation <- function(nyears, lambda, alpha, beta){
  
  data_matrix <- matrix(, nrow = nyears, ncol = 6)
  
  for (z in 1:nyears){
    data_matrix[z][1] <- z
  }
  
  for (yr in 1:nyears){
    
    poisson_sim = rpois(1, lambda)
    
    for (number_of_events in poisson_sim){
      
      if (number_of_events == 1){
        
        beta_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
        data_matrix[yr, 2] <- beta_sim
        
      } else if (number_of_events == 2){
        
          for (i in 2:3){
            
            beta_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
            data_matrix[yr, i] <- beta_sim
            
          }
        
      } else if (number_of_events == 3){
          
          for (i in 2:4){
            
            beta_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
            data_matrix[yr, i] <- beta_sim
        
          }
        
      } else if (number_of_events == 4){
        
          for (i in 2:5){
            
            beta_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
            data_matrix[yr, i] <- beta_sim
        
          }
          
      } else{
        
          for (i in 2:6){
            
            beta_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
            data_matrix[yr, i] <- beta_sim
        }
    
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  
  sorted_matrix <- cbind(data_matrix[,1],t(apply(data_matrix[,2:6],1,function(x) sort(x))))

G <- sorted_matrix %>% as.data.frame %>%
  pivot_longer(-V1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(V1),y=value,color=name,group=name))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(color='Column',x='Time (Years)', y ='Probability')+
  theme_bw()
return(G)
}

manual = occ_simulation(10, 10, 2, 20)
manual
```

What this code does is take an input of the timeframe you want a simulation, then for each year it does a poisson simulation to calculate the number of events that happened in that year. Then depending on the number of events that happened in that year (up to a cut off of 5). Then depending on the number of events that happened it runs a beta simulation for each event so you have a value for the 5 "events" that happened in the year. Then it just places this into a matrix so we have are left with a matrix of values for the number of years against the values for the number of events that have occurred.

```
      [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
 [1,]    1 0.011466314 0.05644778 0.09415982 0.24654834 0.31950041
 [2,]    2 0.005988383 0.05334661 0.07467286 0.10501165 0.18135706
 [3,]    3 0.030178740 0.04501533 0.07642787 0.11537804 0.12156121
 [4,]    4 0.033208015 0.04391486 0.10769396 0.12492813 0.19938551
 [5,]    5 0.026646013 0.03085844 0.06188760 0.10742163 0.16181556
 [6,]    6 0.021271089 0.03010617 0.08581937 0.11578462 0.40768207
 [7,]    7 0.032381818 0.06602770 0.08423590 0.10511102 0.15810456
 [8,]    8 0.030124977 0.04863202 0.08484395 0.08790361 0.09787569
 [9,]    9 0.043273119 0.05148791 0.06314097 0.10162677 0.10308642
[10,]   10 0.045976676 0.06381831 0.07352065 0.08667746 0.11843700
```

Cheers!

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would describe what your cod is doing in text or in comments.

Comment: There are some weird things: for example `poisson_sim = rpois(1, lambda)` so `poisson_sim` has length 1. So `for (number_of_events in poisson_sim)` will only ever have 1 iteration. Is the bug that it should be `for (number_of_events in 1:poisson_sim)`? Or is the bug that `poisson_sim` should have length > 1? Or is it not a bug, just an unnecessary `for` loop? Unless you tell us about your code - what it's supposed to do, what you think each piece is doing - we have no way to know.

Comment: I'll add more now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does everything you talk about in the text, but skips the sorting since you don't mention it and I'm not sure why you do it:

```
occ_simulation2 = function(n_year, lambda, alpha, beta, max_event){
  beta_events = matrix(rbeta(n_year * max_event, shape1 = alpha, shape2 = beta), nrow = n_year)
  n_events_per_year = rpois(n_year, lambda = lambda)
  for(i in which(n_events_per_year < max_event)) {
    beta_events[i, (n_events_per_year[i] + 1):max_event] = NA
  }
  cbind(1:n_year, beta_events)
}

occ_simulation2(n_year = 10, lambda = 10, alpha = 2, beta = 20, max_event = 5)
#       [,1]        [,2]        [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
#  [1,]    1 0.035977205 0.131498127 0.06717396 0.07395549 0.16532084
#  [2,]    2 0.092411677 0.010091762 0.14054564 0.07560796 0.17471096
#  [3,]    3 0.033394007 0.017621993 0.06469264 0.10337253 0.19579706
#  [4,]    4 0.165301623 0.131111006 0.03285909 0.38068480 0.05473743
#  [5,]    5 0.007820079 0.196192197 0.25096961 0.06851775 0.35516715
#  [6,]    6 0.028011863 0.003841574 0.16924708 0.12446178 0.06525773
#  [7,]    7 0.133261625 0.059417090 0.09608348 0.07471339 0.08303839
#  [8,]    8 0.076545497 0.110469131 0.23364757 0.09250536 0.03295593
#  [9,]    9 0.051244148 0.070419370 0.07127251 0.11847306 0.04112807
# [10,]   10 0.104567386 0.188888704 0.02556781 0.10075848 0.02456839
```

Comment: Ah I just did the sorting since when I plot the graph I want the maximum points to be the same colour. Thanks for your answer it is definitely appreciated!

Comment: I tried using that piece of code but it's giving me an error when running it saying that nyear isn't defined and I'm not quite sure where the error is coming from?

Comment: Oh, my typo. I named the argument `nyears` and then used `n_year` in the function. Editing now.

Comment: Went over this code again but it's giving me an error saying that max_event is not defined and I'm not sure where you are getting it from?

Comment: Oh yeah, that should definitely be an argument for the function. I'm adding it in now. Set it to 5 to meet your *"up to a cut off of 5"* criteria.